# Type Conversion in Jinja 2

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to convert the string value in 'snrMinMarginUp' to integer or float in Jinja 2. I tried to lookup every possible solution, but got no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
 {% if 'properties' in value %}
   {{ value['serviceProfile']['snrMinMarginUp'] }}
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `float` or `int` filters to coerce a value to a `float` or `int`, as in:

```
{{ value.serviceProfile.snrMinMarginUp|float }}
```

The example you've given in your question is a little ambiguous -- because you're just displaying the value, it doesn't really matter whether the value is numeric or a string. If this solution doesn't work out for you, please update your question to show a complete example of where things aren't working for you.

Comment: So, I was trying value.serviceProfile.snrMinMarginUp|int, but getting jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'snrMinMarginUp' error

Comment: That seems like an entirely different problem: that's telling you that `value['serviceProfile']` is evaluating to `None`, which suggests your data doesn't look the way you think it looks. This is why it's always a good idea to include any error messages in your question. Please update your question to include the code where you're calling the template, and show how you're debugging the value of `value`.